# Jquery UI Autocomplete - how to use Accent Mapping when drawing data from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a search form on my site where JQuery UI Autocomplete finds matching names. I soon identified the problem with accented names (like Jörn Zaefferer) and found the following solution in the JQuery UI documentation.

```js
$(function() {
  var accentMap = {
    "á": "a",
    "ö": "o",
     "ü": "u"
  };

  var normalize = function(term) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
      ret += accentMap[term.charAt(i)] || term.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
  };

  $("#developer").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("getData.php", {
        term: normalize(request.term)
      }, function(results) {
        response(results);
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete functionality</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   </head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <form>
            <label for="developer">Developer: </label>
            <input id="developer">
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

In this simple example the data (var names) is held in the script, but I want to be able to draw similar data from an external file. I can do this with a different script (using source: getData.php) but without Accent Mapping. I am not sure how to integrate the two together so that I can have Accent Mapping on data sourced from an external file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a small change. Instead of using `$.grep()` you would simple send the un-accented term to your PHP Script. The results would be sent to your Response.

```js
$(function() {
  var accentMap = {
    "á": "a",
    "ö": "o"
  };

  var normalize = function(term) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
      ret += accentMap[term.charAt(i)] || term.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
  };

  $("#developer").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON("getData.php", {
        term: normalize(request.term)
      }, function(results) {
        response(results);
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <form>
    <label for="developer">Developer: </label>
    <input id="developer">
  </form>
</div>
```

So if the User enters, "Jö", the script will send "jo" to `getData.php` and will get a set of results that will include "Jörn Zaefferer".

**Update w/PHP**

You indicated your PHP was using the following code.

```
<?php
$term = $_GET[ "term" ];
$singers = array(
  array(
    "label" => "Skelton, Stuart / singer", 
    "value" => "Skelton, Stuart / singer"
  ),
  array(
    "label" => "Groissböck , Günther / singer",
    "value" => "Groissböck , Günther / singer"
  )
); 
$result = array(); 
foreach($singers as $singer) {
  $singerLabel = $singer[ "label" ]; 
  if ( strpos( strtoupper($singerLabel), strtoupper($term) ) !== false ) { 
    array_push( $result, $singer ); 
  } 
} 
echo json_encode( $result );
?>
```

If the User enters "gr", the JavaScript will normalize it to "gr" and make the GET request. PHP Will accept the request and `$term` will have a value of `"gr"`.

First, for your comparison, I would use `stripos()`:

> stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string

We need to determine if `$term` is a part of any of the Labels. Labels should be normalized. In this test case, it doesn't matter.

```
$result = array(); 
foreach($singers as $singer) {
  if (stripos($singer['label'], $term) !== false) { 
    $result[] = $singer;
    /* Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array, it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function. */
  } 
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Consider normalizing your Labels. Full Example PHP Code:

```
<?php
$term = $_GET[ "term" ];
$singers = array(
    array(
        "label" => "Skelton, Stuart / singer", 
        "value" => "Skelton, Stuart / singer"
    ),
    array(
        "label" => "Groissbock , Gunther / singer",
        "value" => "Groissböck , Günther / singer"
    )
); 
$result = array(); 
foreach($singers as $singer) {
    if (stripos($singer['label'], $term) !== false) { 
        $result[] = $singer;
    } 
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Twisty for your response which draws from the getData.php file and finds matches, but unfortunatley does not find names with accents. I have defined the getData.php file as follows:

Comment: $term = $_GET[ "term" ];
$singers = array(
   array( "label" => "Skelton, Stuart / singer", "value" => "Skelton, Stuart / singer" ),
   array( "label" => "Groissböck , Günther / singer", "value" => "Groissböck , Günther / singer" ));

$result = array();

foreach ($singers as $singer) {
   $singerLabel = $singer[ "label" ];
   if ( strpos( strtoupper($singerLabel), strtoupper($term) )!== false ) {
      array_push( $result, $singer );
   }
}
echo json_encode( $result );

Comment: Using this data Skelton is found, but not Groissböck when entering gr. Is this the correct way to define the data or is there a simpler/better way? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response and recommendations. Unfortunatley with your previously advised JQuery script and the noramlised PHP above I still don't get this to work. sk finds Skelton, but gr does not find Groissbock. If I add a third name (Lundgren, Stewart), then st finds Skelton and Lundgren, but gr still finds nothing (it should find Lundgren in addition to Groissbock).

Comment: While my main concern is to get this to work, I wonder why you recommend normalising the labels? The "label" enry is used to display in the dropdown list, while the "value" entry is returned to the search box. From a user point of view the accents should be in both so that the names are always correctly displayed.

Comment: @minz56 I suggested normalizing the labels as that is what you are using the Search Term to compare with. So if the user enters "gü", the client will normalize it to "gu" and then PHP will try to compare it to "Gü". It won't match. In regards to your search case, can you update your OP and include all relevant code you are using. Please check your Console and your PHP Logs for errors.

Comment: I have updated my OP with the current version that I am testing, based on your comments and feedback. I don't know how to enter the PHP details for the getData.php file but they are exactly the same as your last (normalised) version. Thanks.